# Using count(*) and exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an exam tomorrow and one of the questions on the practice exam was to display the output that a given query provides. So I ran with a working copy database and followed the same syntax.

Below is the data:

```
SELECT vendor_id, name FROM Vendor;
```

```
+-----------+--------------+
| vendor_id | name         |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 | Tiger Direct |
|         2 | Newegg       |
|         3 | Micro Center |
+-----------+--------------+
```

The query given was:

```
SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(*) FROM Vendor v1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Vendor v2 WHERE v2.vendor_id<>v1.vendor_id) GROUP BY vendor_id;
```

```
+-----------+----------+
| vendor_id | COUNT(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 |
|         2 |        1 |
|         3 |        1 |
+-----------+----------+
```

But when I run just a check on what is actually in the exists table I get:

```
SELECT v1.vendor_id FROM Vendor v1, Vendor v2 WHERE v1.vendor_id <> v2.vendor_id;
```

```
+-----------+
| vendor_id |
+-----------+
|         2 |
|         3 |
|         1 |
|         3 |
|         1 |
|         2 |
+-----------+
```

So my question is:
How come the counts are not 2 instead of 1?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I am in the process of learning SQL and this problem got me stumped.

EDIT:

The answers I received were great but now I have to ask:

```
Attends:   
SSN            NUMBER
123456789       670 
123456789       680 
891234567       680 
234567891       670
```

What does this query come up with:

```
select SSN, count(*), avg(Number) from Attends S1
where exists 
  (select * from Attends S2 where S1.SSN <> S2.SSN) group by SSN
```

I now understand that count(*) will always be one since there are only 4 different tuples, but what does that do with AVG(Number). Is there anything that is actually averages out or does it just return with the original number.

Comment: I'd like to let you know that implicit joins like this `FROM Vendor v1, Vendor v2 WHERE v1.vendor_id <> v2.vendor_id` aren't really best practice and instead that explicit joins like `FROM Vendor v1 INNER JOIN Vendor v2 ON v1.vendor_id <> v2.vendor_id` are better practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is returning every row that doesn't match and joining them together, multiplying your number of results, where exists doesn't do that, it applies the reduction without changing the results in memory.

```
SELECT v1.vendor_id, v2.vendor_id v2id FROM Vendor v1, Vendor v2 WHERE v1.vendor_id <> v2.vendor_id;

+-----------+-----------+
| vendor_id | v2id      |
+-----------+-----------+
|         2 |         1 |
|         3 |         1 |
|         1 |         2 |
|         3 |         2 |
|         1 |         3 |
|         2 |         3 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It definitely cleared things up for me

Answer (score 0):

A row is included if it exists in the subquery.  Since you only have 3 rows in the original table, and are not joining anything in, your total number of rows is only ever 3, and hence, count of each id is 1.